# Big IP F5 outbound HTTP issues

Tags: load-balancing, f5-big-ip

We've tried upgrading from 9.x to 10.2 on our F5 Big IP 3400 and everything went over fine apart from one thing. We're unable to establish any outbound HTTP (80) connections from any servers that are assigned to a virtual server. This is something that worked before and is required for certain calls our servers need to make. Interestingly HTTPS (443) connections work fine, it's literally just anything outbound over port 80 seems to fail.

Does anyone know if anything has changed between 9.4 and 10.2 that would mean additional config would need to be made to allow for external HTTP connections?

Any advice would be appreciated, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overwhelming response on this one...

Anyway decided to rebuild the config from scratch rather than trying to port one from a 9.x device, once this had been completed we didn't have any outbound http access issues.

Answer (score -2):

If you had an HTTP profile enabled on the output HTTP virtual server, ot's possible that the servers were sending some HTTP that wasn't parsed successfully by the LTM HTTP filter.

Comment: Just so you know, you're creating bad juju for your company now. You came into a community. Didn't bother to learn how it worked, and then started posting bogus or duplicate answers to questions that were *years* old. Everyone in [chat] is talking about how F5 sent a schill here to drum up some marketing buzz. Definitely **not** the kind of attention that I'm sure you want to bring to your company. So, please. Stop what you're doing and take a little while to learn how Server Fault works. Right now, you're just making F5 look bad.